# Where are unhandled exceptions in command line java application printed out by default? To stdout or stderr?

Tags: java, exception

The title contains the entire question. I would be also grateful for a link to documentation holding an answer.

Comment: I think both places, assuming your server is websphere.

Comment: depends on how you are using the JVM.  For the command line, it's stderr.  For Tomcat, it would be the error log.  For other environment, like application servers, it would also be some kind of a log file.  You need to give more specifics to get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, clarified the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java unhandled exceptions perculate to the top of the thread in which they were thrown.  Java allows you to install a [thread-level uncaught exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).  The behavior when there is no default exception handler specified, as far as I know, is not defined by the Java specification.  Sun's JDK observed default behavior is to print the exception message and its stack trace to stderr.