# Console Printing Order in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-juno

I have a simple Arithmetic Program typed in Eclipse. When run the program in Eclipse the output appears in weird order each time I run. Sometimes The exception comes at last print statement comes first (which is the right way). Some times it comes vise-versa in a jumbled up order. Why it is happening & how to rectify it? Is there any setting to make it print in a right way each time I execute. The below screen shots show how it appears. Please help me rectify this problem.

**Correct Order:**
[image: Correct Order when run]

**Incorrect Order when we run couple times after**
[image: Incorrect Order]

```
 package com;

    public class Abc {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("begin main");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int a = 10;
            int b = 0;
            int c = 0;


            System.out.println("value of a BD is " + a);
            System.out.println("value of b BD is " + b);
            System.out.println("value of c BD is " + c);

            c = a/b; //Arthmetic Exception

            System.out.println("value of a AD is " + a);
            System.out.println("value of b AD is " + b);
            System.out.println("value of c AD is " + c);



        }

    }
```

Comment: When monitors place such a remark it would be helpful if they posted links to the duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit more detail: the output from your print statements is going to `System.out`.  However, the exception messages are going to `System.err` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924348)).  These two are separate output streams that both happen to go to the same place: your console.  They are buffered and processed independently.  In the second situation you show, the `print` statements are buffering up but not yet printed when the exception happens.

**edit** There is an added complication here, which is that the Eclipse console is not a real Windows console.  As noted [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732#c8) among other places, there have in the past been problems with the Eclipse console on Windows platforms because Windows does not give Eclipse a good way to make its console behave just like a native console.  If you add `flush` calls and still have problems, try running your program from a command prompt and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Side note, not related to answer: If you want to add links in form `[description](link)` then don't forget about protocol like `http://` in link. Or better just use `Ctrl+L` option. This will add `http://` part to your link and make your answer easier to edit later.

Answer (score 12):

Two different streams are being used here.  You are using `System.out.` and the exception is printed with `System.err`.  They are buffered, so one's output may print before the other's.

You can call [`System.out.flush();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush()) before the exception line:

```
System.out.flush();
c = a/b;  //Arthmetic Exception
```

Comment: +1. Another approach would be to set error stream to output stream like `System.setErr(System.out);` This way only one stream will need to use console.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't reliably fix the issue...